# CSV to dictionary - Python

Tags: csv, dictionary

For homework we have been asked to build a dictionary from CSV

CSV looks something like this:

```
David,5,6,10,12,15,20
Micheal,9,15,13,20,5,8
John,1,2,5,8,19,10
```

I want convert CSV to Python Dictionary,
But I don't know, how can i do that?

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open('grades.csv') as FileCsv:
    reader = csv.reader(FileCsv)
    for index in reader:
        name = index[0]
        these_grades = list()
        for lines in index[1:]:
            these_grades.append(int(lines))
        print(mean(these_grades))

        # Example
        # average = dict()
        # print('average['John'])
```

The output should be like that:
John's Mean = 7.5

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list (`these_grades = list()`), create the list in a dictionary indexed by name:

```
students = dict()
...
students[name] = list()
```

Then append grades to the list:

```
students[name].append(grade)
```